# Forward request from servlet to jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, model-view-controller

I have a small application (HTML form, servlet as controller and jsp files) and i try to figure out why i cannot to forward the request from servlet to jsp files.

the problem is after submit from html, showed up "HTTP Status 404"

Application flow:

1. submit from html.
2. controller get the name from html.
3. controller supposed to move the request to jsp files.

thanks!

project hierarchy:
http://s23.postimg.org/kgt7r7lwb/Capture.jpg

main.html:

```
<html>
<title>Coupons categories</title>
<body>
  <h1 align="center">Coupons categories</h1>
  <form method="GET" action="Controller">
    Select category 
    Type:
    <select name="type" size=1>
      <option value="restaurants">Restaurants</option>
      <option value="electrics">Electrics</option>
      <option value="hotels">Hotels</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
      <input type="Submit">
   </form>
</body>
<html>
```

controller.java:

```
   @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        //PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        //out.write(request.getPathInfo());

        String path = request.getParameter("type");
        if(path.equals("electrics"))
        {
            request.setAttribute("timestamp", new Date());
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view/electrics.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(path.equals("hotels"))
        {
            request.setAttribute("timestamp", new Date());
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view/hotels.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);          
        }
        else if(path.equals("restaurants"))
        {
            request.setAttribute("timestamp", new Date());
            RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/view/restaurants.jsp");
            dispatcher.forward(request, response);          
        }
    }
```

electrics.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=windows-1255"
    pageEncoding="windows-1255"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>products list...</h2>
    <%
    Object ob = request.getAttribute("timestamp");
    out.println(ob);
    %>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
    <description>
      CouponsServer
    </description>
    <display-name>Controller for CouponsServer</display-name>

    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>uses.server.Controller</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

update:
Probably the problem is in the controller.java.
When i try the following code, i got HTTP Status 500.
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

```
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.write(request.getPathInfo());
    }
```

Comment: If the path parameter on getRequestDispatcher is absolute it is still relative to the servlet context (deploy app name).  Is the '/view' directory a first tier directory of the application?

You can also use a relative path with getRequestDispatcher which is relative to the Servlets current path.

Comment: @user1257931 /view folder in  WebContet. you can see the hierarchy: http://s23.postimg.org/kgt7r7lwb/Capture.jpg

Comment: Does problem appear when you move `main.html` from `view` to `WebContent`?

Comment: @Pshemo yes, still appear.

Comment: @user1257931 please see my edit in the question above.

Comment: Try to build your app with little steps. Don't include form for now. Just run your servlet from its mapped URL address like `http://loclahost:8080/yourAppName/YourServlet` and hardcode redirection to some jsp in `view` (without any conditions). Check if it does work.

Answer (score 10):

Try this

```
 request.getRequestDispatcher("/view/electrics.jsp").forward(req,res);
```

Comment: it is not working. did you have another idea? @Ayushman Ashish

Comment: Have you checked out what is the value of path you are getting on your controller ???

Comment: Did you added the web.xml? I have a feeling that it is responsible for issues

Comment: How about the action in your main.html?  It looks like your Controller mapping is "/Controller" but your main.html is under /view and your action="Controller".  Shouldn't that be action="../Controller" ?

Comment: Yeah i added web.xml too

Comment: it doesnt matter whether it is html or jsp or php, we can give any path in form tag in .html file

Comment: Are you sure?  I believe the url-pattern /Controller will only match scheme://host/webapp/Controller.  It appears that your html is trying to access scheme://host/webapp/view/Controller

Comment: @Ayushman Ashish are you using with eclipse? see my edit in my question above-probably the problem is in the controller.

Comment: no Your controller is working fine.... i just copy paste your code and its working,

Answer (score 0):

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>uses.server.Controller</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
     <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is running fine in my local with the web.xml defined at the end with welcome list or even without it. Try your code running with the dynamic Web content version 2.5 where the web.xml is generated automatically.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
 <description>
      CouponsServer
    </description>
  <display-name>Controller for CouponsServer</display-name>


  <servlet>

    <display-name>Controller</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>uses.server.Controller</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Controller</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Controller</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```