# How to pass an array of numbers to a jsp page?

Tags: java, arrays, jsp, servlets

I'm trying to figure out how an array of numbers stored in an integer array `FibSequence` can be output to a jsp page, preferably in to an input field.

Does anyone know how outputting the array can be achieved on a jsp page?

I can print the array sequence to the console in Eclipse but not sure how with the jsp page:

```
int[] fibSequence = fibonacci_proxy.fibonacciArrayTest(fibMax);

for (int value : fibSequence) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

I've achieved this for *one* number using the following solution:

Servlet(FibonacciServlet):

```
// read form fields
String fibNum = req.getParameter("fibNum");

//send input to the result page using a redirect
resp.sendRedirect(("result.jsp?fibNum=" + fibNum));
```

Jsp Page(result):

```
<% String fibNum = request.getParameter("fibNum"); %>   
<input type="text" name="fibNum" value="<%=fibNum%>" size="40px" style="font-size:30pt;height:60px">
```

Comment: Are you familiar with [`JSTL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnake.html) in general and `<c:forEach>` in particular?

Comment: This question is similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21502149/forward-request-from-servlet-to-jsp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stop attempting to write c code using the java programming language; instead, use objects.

1. Represent the list of fibonacci numbers as a `List<Integer>` or `List<Long>`.
2. Add that variable to the appropriate scope (request, or session seem reasonable) in the servlet.
3. use c:forEach on the page to display the contents of the list.